# Hibernate Parameter Logging does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, logging

It is a Spring Boot application. `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` succeed for another project but not this one. `insert into Table (number) values (?)` shown at console instead of query with parameter.

Any fixes ?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Mobile QT</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.9</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>Backend</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
# https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417172/17135278
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-only
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441828/17135278
 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441828/17135278
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

# https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: A query with parameters will not be shown, also format SQL will format it **not** enable parameter logging. You need to enable `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql` logging (debug or trace to get the parameters).

Comment: But I have enabled `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql`. The outcome is the same even I removed `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`.

Comment: formatting isn't necessary for logging the sql. and again the query won't be logged with parameters, the parameters will be logged separatly not in the query. Finally I'm not sure those logging.level will take effect when deploying as a war (that might depend on how you configured logging in tomcat).